# while loop under fluidrow in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am executing a shiny application where there is while loop inside Modal funtion. Refer below. So the expected output after clicking a button should be a pop up with 4 rows (A, B,C, D). So basically when the `col_name` change so as to number of rows in modal box. In this case there should be 4 rows since we have only (A, B, C, D)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("show","show")
)
shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { 
  col_name <- c("A","B","C","D")
  i <- 1

   observeEvent(input$show,
    showModal(
    modalDialog(
      title = "Edit", 

      while (i < length(col_name)) {
        print(i)
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 4,
                 col_name[i]
                 i = i + 1
          )
        )
      }

      )))
  })
```

Expected output after clicking a button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works, if you have to do it while loop for some reason

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("show","show")
)

server = function(input, output) { 
  col_name <- c("A","B","C","D")
  observeEvent(input$show,{
              text <- ""
               i <- 1
               while (i <= length(col_name)) {
                 print(i)
                 text <- paste(text,col_name[i],"<br/>")
                 i = i+1
               }
               text <- HTML(text)
               showModal(modalDialog(
                 title = "Edit", 
                 text
               ))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

But, if you don't need the while loop, here's a cleaner solution.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("show","show")
)

server = function(input, output) { 
  col_name <- c("A","B","C","D")
  observeEvent(input$show,{
               showModal(modalDialog(
                 title = "Edit", 
                 HTML(paste(col_name, collapse = "<br/>"))
               ))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```